# How to verify if "php://input" is set and not empty

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

How to verify if user have posted with XMLHttpRequest some data to PHP?

This is the best way? If not, how I can do this?

I have the follow code

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // PROBABLY AJAX REQUEST
}
```

My question is, how I can verify `php://input` exists and are not empty? I think the follow code do the work, but need to know if this is a correct way:

```
if(file_get_contents("php://input") == '') {
    // HAVE NOT POSTED
} else {
    // POSTED
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a custom header as part of your AJAX function, and check for the presence of that header in your server-side code.

Perhaps the best way to do this is to generate a key on the server-side, pass that to the client-side code that contains the AJAX call, then make AJAX send it back to the server and verify that it is a valid key. This is the most effective way to prevent someone faking an AJAX request.

---

To check that `php://input` exists and is not empty, use this:

```
$phpinput = file_get_contents("php://input");
// From the docs: "Note: A stream opened with php://input can only be read once"
if( !$phpinput) {
    // phpinput is empty
}
```

Comment: When I do this: `file_get_contents("php://input");` I can't write another time again, because stream will not be available?

Comment: Right. You can only read that stream once, so get it into a variable right away and work on that.

Answer (score 2):

You are not 100% guaranteed to be able to determine whether a script was requested with `XMLHttpRequest`.  You can check `_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`, but this is not guaranteed to be set when you want it or not set when you don't.  You can give it a try, though.

Comment: Ok, I have `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {`, my question is, how I can verify `php://input` exists and are not empty?

Comment: The data should be sent through regular `_POST` or `_GET` .. why do you need to use stdin?

Comment: Because data is not send with POST or GET, can't explain with more details, sorry..